# How can i create the app for different dimension handset with minimum size

Tags: android, apk

I am new in android and I see there are folders like ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xdpi for different handsets. If I put the images for different sizes in these folders then the size of the application increases.

What is the solution of this problem. I also notice one thing that in bin folder one res folder created. Is that also affect the size of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not worry about that, you are on the right track.

You may also want to check here, since this is a nice overview of the topic from the "official" side: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Really, just start your project, BUT make sure the resolution and sizes of your drawable *.png are OK and are themselves not too large. For example don't make a 200x200 image file if you need a 48x48, even though Android will use it without problems and scale it.

ps you might also start accepting and/or upvoting the answers to get more attention and "motivate" the users to help you.  I also didn't know at the begginning...

Happy programming

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will take care of this thing in future

Comment: is there any way that I will create only one size images and used with different handsets

Comment: actually you do not really need to have different sizes for all your images. If you have simple backgrounds, gradients, ... it is not neccessary in most cases. Only when the autoscaling mechanism of Android does not look good anymore you need to scale it yourself. Also you might consider 9-pach file format, this has a "smart" scaling built-in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target all the device types (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi), it would be better that you have different resources for each configuration. If you have resources that are common to all these devices, you can copy them to the respective folders which do not have configuration qualifier (the folder `drawable` for example)

However, you have an option to upload different APKs for different configurations in Google Play as specified by [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) although it is not "encouraged" to do so.

The `bin` folder is generated from the project's classes and resources. The APK is built from the contents of this folder.

Comment: Is there any way that I will create one size image and used on different sets

Comment: You can copy the resources to the configuration independent folder (images to `drawable` folder instead of `drawable-ldpi` etc.). Android will scale them to the density, which may not look good on all the devices